# Deserialize List<Object> C#

Tags: c#, deserialization

I want to assign the `List<Object>` I recieve from this method to a new `List<MyClass>`

```
    public List<Object> Deserialize(string path)
    {
        IFormatter seri = new BinaryFormatter();

        Stream str = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        List<Object> Lista = (List<Object>)(seri.Deserialize(str));
        str.Close();
        return Lista;
    }
```

My intention is to call this method with different Classes and then cast it back to the previous type, but I get an error trying to cast it back afterwards.

Comment: The deserialize part is correct but you were not serializing a List of objects. That is the problem. What was the actual type? It is shown in the message of the InvalidCastExcepton you are getting.

Comment: You should use your `Stream` in a `using` block. Won't fix your problem, but it's strongly recommended or you'll leave handles open.

Comment: Please show `Serialize()`.

Comment: As a general rule, when you have an IEnumerable and want to get it to a type, just use `.OfType<T>()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `Generics`:

```
public List<T> Deserialize<T>(string path)
{
    IFormatter seri = new BinaryFormatter();

    Stream str = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    List<T> Lista = (List<T>)(seri.Deserialize(str));
    str.Close();
    return Lista;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<T> Deserialize<T>(string path)
{
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(path);
}
```